# Spring LocaleChangeInterceptor: how to intercept empty language parameter?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, locale

I've got a trivial `@Configuration` class defining `LocaleResolver` and `LocaleChangeInterceptor` beans. The default locale is set to `Locale.US`. The locale of my computer is `de_DE`.

It works fine as long as the language parameter (`lang` in my case) is provided in HTTP request. That is, for instance, calling `/some/uri?lang=ru` would change the Locale to `ru_RU` from whatever it was before. However, if I now call just `/some/uri`, the locale doesn't change to the default. Rather, it remains the same as the last time the parameter was used. It doesn't match neither my `Accept-Language: de,en-US;` nor the default locale specified in `@Configuration` class.

I'm curious, how this decision is made?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.4

Comment: Did you find the answer?